# Transpose two lists with rightarrow and commas

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to transpose the two following lists:

```
data0 = {99.52267, 93.78726, 99.67644, 99.85036};
error0 = {0.21152, 0.37626, 0.16309, 0.10167};
```

Into `rightArrow` and comma format

```
{99.52267 -> 0.21152, 93.78726 -> 0.37626, 99.67644 -> 0.16309, 
 99.85036 -> 0.10167}
```

Comment: try `Thread[data0 -> error0]`?

Comment: Or 
    MapThread[Rule,{data0,error0}]

Comment: `AssociationThread[data0->error]`. Creates and association that can be used like rule with `Replace`. And is even more efficient.

Comment: There is also `Inner[Rule, data0, error0, List]`